# What is the difference between camber and rocker shaped snowboards?

Tags: snowboarding

When looking at snowboards, they are described as being camber-shaped, rocker-shaped, or a hybrid?

What's the difference between them, and when is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Camber** - Where the ski or snowboard creates a slightly **concave** shape in relation to the snow surface.

1. Better *hard snow and ice grip*.
2. Makes the board or ski "carve" the snow.

**Rocker** - Where the ski or snowboard has a slight **convex** shape in relation to the snow surface.

1. Better *soft snow lift* and float.
2. Makes the board or ski "smear" the snow.

**Hybrid**  - Designs which have rocker at the tip, and camber underfoot. Good for general purpose where either condition may be encountered.

Neither is "better" than the other, they are just tools appropriate for different conditions.

Rocker has enjoyed a cult following, and is now becoming more mainstream.

Pick your poison.

Further reading.
[EvoGear - Camber/ Rocker/ Flat definitions](http://www.evo.com/rocker-guide-what-is-rocker-and-why-does-it-matter.aspx)